# How does Scala return in function

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming, return

I implemented to find max value in the list.
I know that in Scala, You don't have to use 'return', just drop it. 
So I wrote like this,

```
def max(xs: List[Int]):Int={
  if(xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException
  def f(cur_max:Int, xs:List[Int]):Int={
    if(xs.isEmpty)
      cur_max // <- it doesn't return value but just keep going below code.
    if(cur_max < xs.head)
      f(xs.head,xs.tail)
    else
      f(cur_max,xs.tail)
  }
  f(xs.head,xs)
}
```

When it traversed to end of List, it should be returned cur_max value.
However, It just keeps going. Why doesn't it return cur_max. 

To fix this problem, I put 'return' expression that Scala doesn't recommend like ('return cur_max').

Comment: Should the second if block be an else-if rather than just a separate if block?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala it is not enought just to drop value - method returns last evaluated statement. In your case you have two statements:

```
if(xs.isEmpty)
  cur_max
```

and

```
if(cur_max < xs.head)
  f(xs.head,xs.tail)
else
  f(cur_max,xs.tail)
```

So the result of second expression one gets returned.
To fix it add else statement:

```
if(xs.isEmpty)
  cur_max
else if(cur_max < xs.head)
  f(xs.head,xs.tail)
else
  f(cur_max,xs.tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

made several changes. some of them just code style to be more readable like having brackets on `if` expressions.

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {

        def f(cur_max: Int, xs: List[Int]): Int = {
          if (xs.isEmpty) {
            cur_max // <- it doesn't return value but just keep going below code.
          } else {
            if (cur_max < xs.head) {
              f(xs.head, xs.tail)
            }
            else {
              f(cur_max, xs.tail)
            }
          }
        }

        if (xs.isEmpty) {
          throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException
        } else {
          f(xs.head, xs.tail)
        }

      }
```

basically there are some cases on your inner function, which you named `f`:

- the list is empty -> you should return the current max value
- the list is not empty AND the current max is smaller than the first element of the remaining list -> update the current max and call the function with the list tail
- the list is not empty AND the current max is >= than the first element of the remaining list -> call the function with the list tail and the same current max